# how can export java to jar on linux or windows

Tags: javascript, java, linux, bots, discord

I want to export this file
https://github.com/jagrosh/GiveawayBot

So I run it on my own system.
How to convert it from java to jar?

Comment: `jar -cvf` with compiled classes?

Comment: Consider using a build tool like Gradle or Maven.

Comment: Or clone to IDE and export to jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use IDE to make jar of your project or java file. like:- Eclipse,Netbeans etc.
If you want to create jar from command line then use `jar cf jar-file input-file(s)`.

```
jar cvf YourJarName.jar YourClass.class
```

Refer this for more https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

EDIT

Above solution is for creating jars of normal java classes

In your case you have maven project, follow this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-create-jar-pkg-maven-no-ide.html

Comment: Give me an example of my link
please

Comment: @loser check EDITs